How to fix "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" in a Node.js TypeScript project with Prisma and Turborepo?
I am setting up a monorepo using Turborepo that includes both a Next.js app and a Node.js TypeScript project. For the database setup, I followed the Prisma guide for Turborepo, which works fine in the Next.js app. However, I am encountering an issue in the Node.js TypeScript project. When I try to run the Node.js TypeScript project using the command npm run start, I get the following error:
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Project-Structure/
├── apps/
│   ├── web/          # Next.js project
│   └── services/    # Node.js TypeScript project
|       └──dist
|       └──node_modules
|       └──src
|          └──index.ts
|       └──package.json
|       └──tsconfig.json  
├── packages/
│   └── db/           # Shared PrismaClient setup
|       └── node_modules
|       └── prisma
|       └── src
|            └── index.ts
|       └──.env
|       └──package.json
├── typescript-config/
│   ├── base.json
│   ├── nextjs.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── react-library.json
├── package.json
├── turbo.json
└── tsconfig.json

apps/services/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

packages/prisma/src/index.ts
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient();
};

declare const globalThis: {
  prismaGlobal: ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>;
} & typeof global;

const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton();

export default prisma;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma;


How can I properly configure my Node.js TypeScript project? Any and best practices for intializing. Please let me know if any other file is required.
